# How to compute an integral over a sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $r > 0$ then how to compute an integral $\int_{\partial B(0,r)}|x|^{-n}dS(x)$ where $S(x)$ is a standard spherical measure. I tried to move to polar coordninates, but i have difficulties with the $S(x)$. How i can move from $dS(x)$ to regural $dx$?

I was able to compute the integral $\int_{B(0,r)}|x|^{-n}dx$ using the fact that $|x|$ is a spherical function. Can i apply this result somehow with my problem?

Comment: Do you know what $dS$ is? Usually your textbook will contain a formula for it in terms of polar co-ordinates $(\theta, \phi)$.

Comment: defenition of $dS(x)$ wasnt given o.o

Comment: I don't know where this exercise came from, but you will not be able to complete it without a definition of all the terms. You may want to look up "surface integrals" or "integration on a sphere" on a search engine or (better) in a library. There are some notes here, but it sounds like you need to do some broader reading before attempting this. https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes02/v9.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your special case, the integrand $|x|^{-n}$ has the constant value $r^{-n}$ on the sphere $\partial B(0,r)$, so
$$\int_{\partial B(0,r)} |x|^{-n} dS(x)
= \int_{\partial B(0,r)} r^{-n} dS(x)
= r^{-n} \int_{\partial B(0,r)} dS(x)
= r^{-n} \operatorname{Area}\bigl( \partial B(0,r) \bigr)
.
$$
(If you're in $\mathbf{R}^m$, the area is $r^{m-1}$ times the [area of the unit sphere in $\mathbf{R}^m$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere#General_area_and_volume_formulas).
For $m=3$, it's the familiar $4 \pi r^2$.)